ProxySQL can’t connect to XtraDB
I can connect directly from the server where proxysql is deployed to xtraDB, but cannot connect to xtraDB via proxysql.
my proxysql conf
I can connect directly from the server where proxysql is deployed to xtraDB:

ubuntu@proxysql:\~$ mysql -u cerebra -pnew_password -h 51.12.210.119 -P 3306
mysql: \[Warning\] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
Welcome to the MySQL monitor. Commands end with ; or \\g.
Your MySQL connection id is 828
Server version: 8.0.36-28.1 Percona XtraDB Cluster (GPL), Release rel28, Revision bfb687f, WSREP version 26.1.4.3

Copyright (c) 2000, 2024, Oracle and/or its affiliates.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type ‘help;’ or ‘\\h’ for help. Type ‘\\c’ to clear the current input statement.

mysql\> show databases
→ ;
±-------------------+
| Database |
±-------------------+
| cerebra |
| information_schema |
| mysql |
| performance_schema |
| sys |
±-------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

But via proxysql:

ubuntu@proxysql:\~$ mysql -u cerebra -pnew_password -h 127.0.0.1 -P 6033
mysql: \[Warning\] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
Welcome to the MySQL monitor. Commands end with ; or \\g.
Your MySQL connection id is 9
Server version: 8.0.36-28.1 Percona XtraDB Cluster (GPL), Release rel28, Revision bfb687f, WSREP version 26.1.4.3 (ProxySQL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2024, Oracle and/or its affiliates.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type ‘help;’ or ‘\\h’ for help. Type ‘\\c’ to clear the current input statement.

mysql\> show databases
→ ;
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user ‘cerebra’@‘135.225.106.78’ (using password: YES)
mysql\>

log file:

ubuntu@proxysql:\~$ sudo tail -f /var/lib/proxysql/proxysql.log
2024-09-11 08:05:39 mysql_connection.cpp:999:handler(): \[ERROR\] Failed to mysql_real_connect() on 51.12.211.18:3306 , FD (Conn:43 , MyDS:43) , 1045: Access denied for user ‘cerebra’@‘135.225.106.78’ (using password: YES).
2024-09-11 08:05:39 mysql_connection.cpp:999:handler(): \[ERROR\] Failed to mysql_real_connect() on 20.240.210.183:3306 , FD (Conn:43 , MyDS:43) , 1045: Access denied for user ‘cerebra’@‘135.225.106.78’ (using password: YES).
2024-09-11 08:05:39 mysql_connection.cpp:999:handler(): \[ERROR\] Failed to mysql_real_connect() on 20.240.210.183:3306 , FD (Conn:43 , MyDS:43) , 1045: Access denied for user ‘cerebra’@‘135.225.106.78’ (using password: YES).
2024-09-11 08:05:39 mysql_connection.cpp:999:handler(): \[ERROR\] Failed to mysql_real_connect() on 51.12.210.119:3306 , FD (Conn:43 , MyDS:43) , 1045: Access denied for user ‘cerebra’@‘135.225.106.78’ (using password: YES).
2024-09-11 08:05:39 mysql_connection.cpp:999:handler(): \[ERROR\] Failed to mysql_real_connect() on 51.12.211.18:3306 , FD (Conn:43 , MyDS:43) , 1045: Access denied for user ‘cerebra’@‘135.225.106.78’ (using password: YES).
2024-09-11 08:05:39 mysql_connection.cpp:999:handler(): \[ERROR\] Failed to mysql_real_connect() on 20.240.210.183:3306 , FD (Conn:43 , MyDS:43) , 1045: Access denied for user ‘cerebra’@‘135.225.106.78’ (using password: YES).
2024-09-11 08:05:39 mysql_connection.cpp:999:handler(): \[ERROR\] Failed to mysql_real_connect() on 51.12.211.18:3306 , FD (Conn:43 , MyDS:43) , 1045: Access denied for user ‘cerebra’@‘135.225.106.78’ (using password: YES).
2024-09-11 08:05:39 mysql_connection.cpp:999:handler(): \[ERROR\] Failed to mysql_real_connect() on 20.240.210.183:3306 , FD (Conn:43 , MyDS:43) , 1045: Access denied for user ‘cerebra’@‘135.225.106.78’ (using password: YES).
2024-09-11 08:05:39 mysql_connection.cpp:999:handler(): \[ERROR\] Failed to mysql_real_connect() on 51.12.210.119:3306 , FD (Conn:43 , MyDS:43) , 1045: Access denied for user ‘cerebra’@‘135.225.106.78’ (using password: YES).
2024-09-11 08:05:39 mysql_connection.cpp:999:handler(): \[ERROR\] Failed to mysql_real_connect() on 51.12.211.18:3306 , FD (Conn:43 , MyDS:43) , 1045: Access denied for user ‘cerebra’@‘135.225.106.78’ (using password: YES).


i want to connect to xtradbs via proxysql
